Can I ask parachute-related questions here, and if not where can I ask them?
I have a few parachute-related questions, and I asked one of them here on Aviation.SE a while ago (I think probably 1 month now). The result is 6 downvotes and being closed as off-topic. Both the aviation.SE's help center on-topic page and this meta post about what's on-topic don't say anything about parachutes. As I see it, parachutes had affected and had been affected by aircraft ever since it's invention, and is an integral part of aviation. Why is it off-topic? If it is off-topic, why didn't the help center specifically state so? I'm pretty sure many other people had this question before, since parachutes are extremely closely related to aviation, if not completely related. Also, if it is off-topic, where can I ask about them? I'll appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

The Help Center would never be able to have a list that explicitly states everything that is off-topic.  Starting with the expectation that "if ___ is off-topic, why doesn't the Help Center specifically state so" is never going to match up with reality.  If a particular subject doesn't show up in the discussions of what is considered on-topic, then that right there is probably a good indicator.

Well, we have a parachute tag, so clearly some parachute questions are on topic. This is a site about Aviation, so your question would need to be about the aviation use of parachutes and not, for example, whether you could throw an elephant out an aeroplane!
Here's some examples of good parachute questions:

Do any commercial airline models have a parachute at rear to help in landings?
Why are commercial flights not equipped with parachutes for the passengers?
Why don't pilots parachute from small planes that are in distress?

If there is a subject that interests you, look for highly upvoted questions and answers in that category, as that is usually a good way to learn what sort of questions are most acceptable to the wider community.

You got me: throw an elephant out of an aircraft is exactly the post I'm talking about (the one that got 6 downvotes and closed as off-topic). So do you mean it's an example of a bad parachute question? Thanks for the help, BTW.

Actually I don't think that was question was bad per se, it was just off topic. You were mainly asking about the physics of the maximum possible load and that has nothing to do with Aviation. You could have also avoided the "incredulous factor" by not focusing on elephants. There are, after all, many other more sensible heavy things dropped from aeroplanes, such as Humvees.

Thanks for the explanation. So that question is not bad, it's just not very suitable for this site. Do you suggest any other sites that the question may be on-topic? Thanks for any advice! (PS: Elephants are crazy, but I think Humvees are not that much better. All of those are hypothetical situations, after all.  Still, as the video you linked suggests, Humvees had actually been dropped by parachute before, so I guess it's slightly more reasonable than elephants.)
